# jQuery Autocomplete not showing values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can not seem to get this autocomplete working. I am using this for my search field:

```
<input type="text" data-cat="1" class="form-control interest-search" placeholder="Find some interests">
```

I am then making an ajax request to my server to search the database for similar items like this:

```
var search = null;
$(document).on('keyup', '.interest-search', function(){
    clearTimeout(search);
    var $this = $(this);
    search = setTimeout(function(){
        var search = $this.val();
        var category = $this.attr('data-cat');
        $.post('/suggest/interest', JSON.stringify({interest: search, category: category}), function(data){
            $('input[data-cat=' + category + ']').autocomplete({
                source: data
            });
        }, 'json');
    }, 200);
});
```

I then get a json array of results back that look like this:

```
[
    {"label":"biking","value":"2","total":"1"},
    {"label":"billiards","value":"3","total":"3"}
]
```

But what happens, is nothing displays. I have no errors either.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s7zakqzo/

Comment: Hmmm, no errors? I'm assuming that you have jQuery, jQuery UI, and the CSS all loading properly?

Comment: yeah, it is all there. They are loaded in the header. jquery `1.11.3` and bootstrap `3.3.5`

Comment: I have added a fiddle

Comment: I got it! I defined search twice, and it was breaking it for some reason. I changed `var search = $this.val();` to `var q = $this.val();` and it works

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Weird - that didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var search = null;

var data = [
    {label:"biking",value:"2",total:"1"},
    {label:"billiards",value:"3",total:"3"}
];

$(document).on('keyup', '.interest-search', function(){
    clearTimeout(search);
    var $this = $(this);
    search = setTimeout(function(){
        var search = $this.val();
        $this.autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
    }, 200);
});
```

Change `$('input[data-cat=' + category + ']')` to `$this`. It fixes the problem.